# Write adb serial number to file

Tags: android, adb

How do I write the output ie, serial no, from the adb command:

```
'adb get-serialno'
```

to a file?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows: `adb get-serialno >> serial.txt`

Comment: Same works for unix/linux if the file does not exist. Otherwise use only one `>` instead of two to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux or Mac:

```
adb get-serialno > serial.txt
```